# Python add label to parent widget

Tags: python-3.x, gtk

I have currently this code:

```
import gi
import gettext
_ = gettext.gettext

gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('Gdk', '3.0')

from gi.repository import Gtk, Gio, GLib

class Invoicy(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):

        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Invoicy")
        self.set_border_width = 10
        self.set_default_size(800, 600)

        header_bar = Gtk.HeaderBar()
        header_bar.set_show_close_button(True)
        header_bar.props.title = "Invoicy"
        self.set_titlebar(header_bar)

        newbutton = Gtk.Button(None,image=Gtk.Image.new_from_gicon(Gio.ThemedIcon(name="document-new"), Gtk.IconSize.LARGE_TOOLBAR))
        header_bar.pack_start(newbutton)

        menubutton = Gtk.Button(None,image=Gtk.Image.new_from_gicon(Gio.ThemedIcon(name="open-menu"), Gtk.IconSize.LARGE_TOOLBAR))
        menubutton.connect("clicked", self.settingsdialog)
        header_bar.pack_end(menubutton)

        label = Gtk.Label("test")

        self.add(label)


win = Invoicy()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Now I want, when I click on `newbutton` to call a function that add new label in the main window.
Is this possible? When yes, how could I do this?
I tried it for several hours now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the `connect` method on the "newbutton" to add a callback handler function that adds the label.

```
newbutton.connect("clicked", self.on_newbutton_clicked)
```

And a a callback handler method in your `Window` class:

```
def on_newbutton_clicked(self, button):
    label = Gtk.Label("test")
    self.add(label)
```